clang-tidy fails to report prefer-member-initializer correctly
I have this class constructor
struct CosseratRodPrecomputation {
    CosseratRodPrecomputation(Scalar L0,
                              const Vec3 &xA_,
                              const Vec3 &xB_,
                              const Vec3 &vA_,
                              const Vec3 &vB_,
                              const Mat3 &RA_,
                              const Mat3 &RB_)
        : one_over_L0(1.0 / L0)
        , xA(xA_)
        , xB(xB_)
        , vA(vA_)
        , vB(vB_)
        , L(deltaX.norm())
        , one_over_L(1.0 / L)
        , RA(RA_)
        , RB(RB_)

    {
        deltaX = xA-xB;
    }
...
};

This code is wrong, because deltaX is initialized after L, which depends on deltaX.
If I move any other of the member initializations to the ctor body (for example, xA = xA_), clang-tidy reports I should be initializing it in the member initializer (cppcoreguidelines-prefer-member-initializer). However, it fails to report the same issue for deltaX.
Is this a bug in clang-tidy or am I missing something here?
Here is a minimal example.
https://clang-tidy.godbolt.org/z/orcWsf7Kd

Move L(deltaX.norm()) to L = deltaX.norm() into the constructor body. clang-tidy reports about member initializers only to members that are initialized with constructor parameters.

Moving L initialization to constructor body triggers a clang-tidy warning: it says I should put it back in the member initializer. That is very confusing, why does it want to put L in the member intializer but not delta?

Impossible to guess w/o a [mre].

Added a minimal example
